# SQL-Server, confront Customers with Employees function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, northwind

I might have a really simple question, but it doesn't seem i can find the solution yet. Basically, i have to write a SQL-Server function, based on Northwind DB. It has to:

Take 2 dates as arguments and display, without repetition these **Customer's** data `ID  |  Name  | City  |  Address` , for those customers *where the total purchase he had made from at least one* **Employee** , is greater than the average sale made by this Employee between the two dates.

So the main steps should be:
1. Retrieve the total purchase made from a Customer from each **Employee**. I know how to get the total purchase from each **Company**:

```
SELECT 
Customers.CompanyName,    SUM(UnitPrice*Quantity)
FROM Orders inner join [Order Details]
ON Orders.OrderID=[Order Details].OrderID INNER JOIN 
Customers ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID
GROUP BY Customers.CompanyName
```

But how can i get those made from each employee?

2.Confront this with the average sales of this **Employee** between the given dates. I can get the average for each employee:

```
SELECT FirstName+' '+LastName, AVG(UnitPrice*Quantity)
FROM Orders inner join [Order Details]
ON Orders.OrderID=[Order Details].OrderID
INNER JOIN Employees 
ON Orders.EmployeeID=Employees.EmployeeID
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN @dt1 and @dt2
GROUP BY FirstName+' '+LastName
```

Note that i'm only pasting the query part, but here, the Employee should depend on the first query (probably this should be put inside a subquery)

Everything should be put inside a single function (it should not be split in two). The Northwind DB diagram is: [Northwind Diagram](http://merc.tv/img/fig/Northwind_diagram.jpg) . Please help!

Comment: What do you have so far? Have you written a query to return part 1 or 2?

Comment: 921 points...you know how this place works.

Comment: Sorry guys, you have totally right, but i was in a hurry. I'm updating my question right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope I got the logic right:

```
create function x (@from datetime, @to datetime)
returns table
as
return (
    with cust as (
        select o.customerid, o.employeeid, sum(unitprice*quantity) as cust_purchase
        from orders o
        inner join [order details] d on o.orderid=d.orderid
        where o.orderdate between @from and @to
        group by o.customerid, o.employeeid
    ),
    emp as (
        select o.employeeid, avg(unitprice*quantity) as emp_sale
        from orders o
        inner join [order details] d on o.orderid=d.orderid
        where o.orderdate between @from and @to
        group by o.employeeid
    )
    select c.customerid, c.companyname, c.city, c.address
    from cust
    inner join emp on cust.employeeid = emp.employeeid
    and cust.cust_purchase > emp.emp_sale
    inner join customers c on cust.customerid = c.customerid
)
go

select * from x ('19980401', '19980430')
```

Comment: This is the first time encountering the "WITH" clause. I feel so dumb right now. This solution seems nice and really simple, thank you very much :)

Comment: You could do it all with poor old subqueries :)

Comment: I've tried to do so, but i've ended up doing a real mess. As i said i haven't read about CTE before, but it seems to come in help precisely to avoid nesting subqueries, ending up with an unreadable code.